# AWS Lambda Node.js Full-ICU

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, intl

I run node.js app localy with this command:

```
$ node --icu-data-dir=node_modules/full-icu app.local.js
```

How to specify icu-data-dir in AWS Lambda environment?

Thanks

Comment: I had this previously working with the `nodejs6.10` runtime, but it stopped working after upgrading to the `nodejs8.10` runtime.

More info on the AWS forums here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=866766&#866766

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `NODE_ICU_DATA` environment variable so that it points to a directory where the correct ICU `.dat` file can be found.

If you install the `full-icu` package using the node version that matches the one used by your lambdas, you should automatically get the correct `.dat` file. E.g. when using the runtime `nodejs10.x`:

```
npx -p node@10.x npm i full-icu
```

This installs `node_modules/full-icu/`, and you should see the file `icudt62l.dat` in that directory. The exact name of the file depends on the version of node you're using.

If you're deploying the whole `node_modules` directory as part of your lambda, `NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu/` (equivalent to `NODE_ICU_DATA=/var/task/node_modules/full-icu`) should work. Otherwise, you can deploy just the `.dat` file as part of your lambda and point `NODE_ICU_DATA` at the directory where you deployed the file.

If you're still getting an error and you're sure that `NODE_ICU_DATA` is correct, make sure that the `.dat` file version is correct.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda with NodeJS 12.x seems to be compiled wth full-icu support.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const langs = ["ar","bg","br","ch","cn","cs","da","da","de","dk","el","en","es","ev","fi","fr","hr","hu","it","ja","jp","ko","nl","no","pl","pt","pt","ro","ru","sk","sl","sv","tr"];
    for (let lang of langs){
        console.log(lang, Intl.DateTimeFormat(lang, {year:'numeric', month:'long', day: 'numeric'}).format(new Date()));
    }
};
```

whith result of :

```
ar ٢٩ يناير ٢٠٢١
bg 29 януари 2021 г.
br 29 Genver 2021
ch January 29, 2021
cn January 29, 2021
cs 29. ledna 2021
da 29. januar 2021
da 29. januar 2021
de 29. Januar 2021
dk January 29, 2021
el 29 Ιανουαρίου 2021
en January 29, 2021
es 29 de enero de 2021
ev January 29, 2021
fi 29. tammikuuta 2021
fr 29 janvier 2021
hr 29. siječnja 2021.
hu 2021. január 29.
it 29 gennaio 2021
ja 2021年1月29日
jp January 29, 2021
ko 2021년 1월 29일
nl 29 januari 2021
no January 29, 2021
pl 29 stycznia 2021
pt 29 de janeiro de 2021
pt 29 de janeiro de 2021
ro 29 ianuarie 2021
ru 29 января 2021 г.
sk 29. januára 2021
sl 29. januar 2021
sv 29 januari 2021
tr 29 Ocak 2021
```

Answer (score -1):

As pointed in the [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html), you can also use an environment variable, such as `NODE_ICU_DATA=/some/directory`.

You can easily setup environment variables in your lambda instance settings.