# How to add ICU data to Node.js in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda, icu

My question is similar to an [existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195309/aws-lambda-node-js-full-icu), but I'm using webpack and thus don't even have a "node_modules" directory.

I've still tried the following environment variable settings without success:

```
NODE_ICU_DATA: 'node_modules/full-icu'
NODE_ICU_DATA: '/var/task/node_modules/full-icu/icudt58l.dat'
NODE_ICU_DATA: '/var/task/node_modules/full-icu/icudt60l.dat'
```

All without success, the lambdas simply refuse to start and a log message is show in CloudWatch:

```
/var/lang/bin/node: could not initialize ICU (check NODE_ICU_DATA or --icu-data-dir parameters)
```

I found very little about this problem on Google, which seems curious given that it should concern so many that are building internal apps on AWS lambda.

Comment: Someone else also posted the question to the full-icu's github repository and didn't get a response: https://github.com/unicode-org/full-icu-npm/issues/31

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're deploying the correct `.dat` file version into the directory defined by `NODE_ICU_DATA`. In my case, the correct file was `icudt62l.dat` when using the runtime `nodejs10.x` for my lambdas. If you're not deploying `node_modules` as part of your lambda, you can grab the correct `.dat` file and deploy that.

I ran into the same error message when upgrading the runtime version of some old lambdas from `nodejs6.10` to `nodejs10.x`. In my case, the file `icudt58l.dat` (compatible with `nodejs6.10`) was deployed into the project root, and the value of `NODE_ICU_DATA` was `.` (i.e. the directory where my lambda executes, equivalent to `/var/task/`).

To get a compatible `.dat` file, I re-installed the `full-icu` package using the node version used by the lambdas:

```
npx -p node@10.x npm i full-icu
```

**It's important that the version of the `.dat` file is correct for the runtime version your lambdas are using**. Initially, I made the mistake of just running `npm i full-icu` using node version `10.0` but this installed the wrong version of the `.dat` file and I just got the same error message again.

Finally, I copied the file `node_modules/full-icu/icudt62l.dat` into the project root and deleted the old `icudt58l.dat` so that it ends up in `/var/task/` where the lambda can find it when `NODE_ICU_DATA=.`.